# an issue regarding php string length chacking

Tags: php

bellow is a script that inserts data into a table. I have used the strlen() function to check the length of the string and it does return an error if the length of the string is bellow the limit but it does NOT stop the query from adding another row to the table. How can I do that. Thank you very much

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","zzzz","xxxxzzz2","my_project");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

//$sql="INSERT INTO Product (product_name, product_cond, product_price, product_cat, product_region, email, phone_num)
//VALUES
//('$_POST[ProductName]','$_POST[ProductCond]','$_POST[ProductPrice]','$_POST[ProductCat]','$_POST[ProductRegion]','$_POST[Email]','$_POST[PhoneNumber]')";

$sql="INSERT INTO Product (product_name, product_cond, product_price, product_cat, product_region, email, phone_num)
VALUES
('$_POST[product_name]','$_POST[product_cond]','$_POST[product_price]','$_POST[product_cat]','$_POST[product_region]','$_POST[Email]','$_POST[PhoneNumber]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }

//here is the part in question

if (strlen($ProductName) < 10) 
{  
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($sql));
}
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Move your insert statement ___after___ the length check.... if it's before that, then it will run before that

Comment: But a test for a long string in PHP ___won't___ generate a MySQL error, so displaying the MySQLi error if strlen($ProductName) < 10 is meaningless... there isn't a MySQLi error

Comment: Mark is right , Btw where are you assigning a value to your `$ProductName` ?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran I do it it the html part of the script. its another file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're checking the length of the string after the insert, you need to do the check before the insert, like this:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","zzzz","xxxxzzz2","my_project");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

if (strlen($ProductName) < 10)
{
    die('Error: product name too short!');
}

$sql="INSERT INTO Product (product_name, product_cond, product_price, product_cat,     product_region, email, phone_num)
VALUES
('$_POST[product_name]','$_POST[product_cond]','$_POST[product_price]','$_POST[product_cat]','$_POST[product_region]','$_POST[Email]','$_POST[PhoneNumber]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

//here is the part in question


echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

---

*edit* Using a `die` is not considered best practice. The better way to do this, is wrapping it (for example) in an `if` statement, like this:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","zzzz","xxxxzzz2","my_project");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
} elseif (strlen($ProductName) < 10) {
    echo 'Error: product name too short!';
} else {
    $sql= "INSERT INTO Product (product_name, product_cond, product_price, product_cat, product_region, email, phone_num)
          VALUES
          ('$_POST[product_name]','$_POST[product_cond]','$_POST[product_price]','$_POST[product_cat]','$_POST[product_region]','$_POST[Email]','$_POST[PhoneNumber]')";

    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
        echo 'Error: ' . mysqli_error($con);
    } else {
        echo "1 record added";
    }
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

---

*edit 2* Based on your comment, if you want to check if the string isn't more then 50 chars, you can use something like this:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","zzzz","xxxxzzz2","my_project");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
} elseif (strlen($ProductName) < 10) {
    echo 'Error: product name too short!';
} elseif (strlen($ProductName) > 50) {
    echo 'Error: product name too long!';
} else {
    $sql= "INSERT INTO Product (product_name, product_cond, product_price, product_cat, product_region, email, phone_num)
          VALUES
          ('$_POST[product_name]','$_POST[product_cond]','$_POST[product_price]','$_POST[product_cat]','$_POST[product_region]','$_POST[Email]','$_POST[PhoneNumber]')";

    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
        echo 'Error: ' . mysqli_error($con);
    } else {
        echo "1 record added";
    }
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: I have one more question how do you add another condition so it also checks for max limit also e.g. >50 error: must be less than...

Answer (score 0):

The order of the script is wrong, the logic needs to be like so:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","zxzxzx","zxzxzx","my_project");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

//$sql="INSERT INTO Product (product_name, product_cond, product_price, product_cat, product_region, email, phone_num)
//VALUES
//('$_POST[ProductName]','$_POST[ProductCond]','$_POST[ProductPrice]','$_POST[ProductCat]','$_POST[ProductRegion]','$_POST[Email]','$_POST[PhoneNumber]')";

$sql="INSERT INTO Product (product_name, product_cond, product_price, product_cat, product_region, email, phone_num)
VALUES
('$_POST[product_name]','$_POST[product_cond]','$_POST[product_price]','$_POST[product_cat]','$_POST[product_region]','$_POST[Email]','$_POST[PhoneNumber]')";

// First thing is to ask your condition..

if (strlen($ProductName) < 10) 
{  
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($sql));
}

echo "1 record added";
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }



mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I would suggest you to use bindings for your parameters on your query to prevent SQL injections. [PDO bindings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)